# tpm_crb msft0101 error after unexpected shutdown

Tags: 16.04

I was running a python script that was supposed to run for around an hour. But before completion, my laptop went our of charge and turned off. And when I tried to power on my laptop, after the grub, I'm getting the following message

```
tcm_crb MSFT0101:00: cant request region from resource [mem 0xfed40080=0xfed40fff]
```

I tried using the recovery mode but it takes me nowhere. I end up in a root shell command prompt. Checked for solutions online, but relevant information was not found.

Thanks in advance!